# Альтернация в регулярных выражениях

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Вообщем пытаюсь решить такую проблему:
Строка может начинаться либо с "978-" или с "979-"  после тире, для первого случая могут быть только цифра с 0-7, а для второго только с 10-12

Например:

978-5

979-10

Пытаюсь использовать такое выражение:

> 979-1[0-2] | 978-[0-7]

Раздельно правая и левая часть работают, но как только ставлю ИЛИ то перестают работать, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Т.е. совпадение должно быть равно всей строке? [`^(979-1[0-2]|978-[0-7])$`](https://regex101.com/r/ySrNkk/1)?

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, спасибо. Оказалось дело в пробелах :D я дурак, привык после условных операторов пробелы лепить

Answer (score 1):

Упс, проблема была в пробелах до и после |

Answer (score 1):

Тут можно использовать следующее выражение:

```
^(979-1[0-2]|978-[0-7])$
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/ySrNkk/1)

Т.е. нужно заключить чередующиеся шаблоны в круглые скобки. Помните, что пробелы в регулярных выражениях не являются знаками форматирования по умолчанию, для этого нужно использовать соответствующий флаг (`re.X` или `re.VERBOSE` в Python, шаблонный вариант `(?x)` - в зависимости от библиотеки регулярных выражений), так что пробелы вокруг `|` необходимо удалить, если их нет в тексте, в котором осуществляется поиск.